# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a new error with the code below.  Originally I had some classes that were named different.  I changed them, but new errors arose.  The code below will not run correctly because I had to remove some of it for the post.  It had too many characters.  Hopefully I didn't get rid of the part that is needed to be fixed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class VolCalc extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ 
    private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane; 
    private JPanel general; 
    private JPanel pools; 

    private JPanel tempCalc; 
    private JPanel options; 
    private JPanel hotTub; 
    private JComponent date; 
    JTextField lengthText, widthText, depthText, volumeText; 

    public void CalcVolume(){

        JPanel customers = new JPanel();

        setTitle("Pools"); 
        setSize(300, 200); 

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(); 
        topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); 
        getContentPane().add( topPanel ); 

        createGeneral(); 
        createPools(); 
        createOptions(); 

        jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(); 
        jtabbedPane.addTab("General", general); 
        jtabbedPane.addTab("Pools", pools); 

        jtabbedPane.addTab("Temp Calculator", tempCalc); 
        jtabbedPane.addTab("Options", options); 
        jtabbedPane.addTab("Hot Tubs", hotTub);

        topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    }

    /*      CREATE GENERAL    */

    public void createGeneral(){ 
        general = new JPanel(); 
        general.setLayout(null); 

        JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel("Todays Date"); 
        dateLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 150, 20); 
        general.add(dateLabel); 

        JFormattedTextField date = new JFormattedTextField( 
        java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); 
        date.setEditable(false); 
        date.setBounds(150,15,150,20); 
        general.add(date); 

        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit"); 
        Exit.setBounds(10,80,150,30); 
        Exit.addActionListener(this); 
        Exit.setBackground(Color.red); 
        general.add(Exit); 
    }

    /*      CREATE POOLS    */

    public void createPools(){ 
        pools = new JPanel(); 
        pools.setLayout(null); 

        JLabel lengthLabel = new JLabel( "Enter the length of swimming pool(ft):"); 
        lengthLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 260, 20); 
        pools.add(lengthLabel); 

        lengthText = new JTextField(); 
        lengthText.setBounds( 260, 15, 150, 20 ); 
        pools.add( lengthText ); 

        JLabel widthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the width of the swimming pool(ft):"); 
        widthLabel.setBounds(10, 60, 260, 20); 
        pools.add(widthLabel); 

        widthText = new JTextField(); 
        widthText.setBounds(260, 60, 150, 20); 
        pools.add(widthText); 

        JLabel depthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the average depth the swimming pool(ft):"); 
        depthLabel.setBounds(10, 100, 260, 20); 
        pools.add( depthLabel); 

        depthText = new JTextField(); 
        depthText.setBounds(260, 100, 150, 20); 
        pools.add(depthText); 

        JLabel volumeLabel = new JLabel("The pool volume is:(ft ^3"); 
        volumeLabel.setBounds(10, 200, 260, 20); 
        pools.add(volumeLabel); 

        volumeText = new JTextField(); 
        volumeText.setBounds(260, 200, 150, 20); 
        volumeText.setEditable(false); 
        pools.add(volumeText); 

        JButton calcVolume = new JButton("Calculate Volume"); 
        calcVolume.setBounds(150,250,150,30); 
        calcVolume.addActionListener(this); 

        pools.add(calcVolume); 

        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit"); 
        Exit.setBounds(350,250,80,30); 
        Exit.addActionListener(this); 
        Exit.setBackground(Color.white); 
        pools.add(Exit); 
    }

    public void createOptions() 
    { 
        options = new JPanel(); 
        options.setLayout( null ); 
        JLabel labelOptions = new JLabel("Change Company Name:"); 
        labelOptions.setBounds( 150, 50, 150, 20 ); 
        options.add( labelOptions ); 

        JTextField newTitle = new JTextField(); 
        newTitle.setBounds( 150, 70, 150, 20 ); 
        options.add( newTitle ); 

        JButton newName = new JButton("Set New Name");
        newName.setBounds(100,115,150,30);
        newName.addActionListener(this);
        newName.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        options.add(newName);

        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
        Exit.setBounds(250,115,80,30);
        Exit.addActionListener(this);
        Exit.setBackground(Color.red);
        options.add(Exit);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){ 
        JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource(); 
        String buttonLabel = button.getText(); 

        if ("Exit".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){ 
            Exit_pressed(); return; 
        } 

        if ("Set New Name".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){ 
            New_Name(); 
            return; 
        } 

        if ("Calculate Volume".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){ 
            Calculate_Volume(); return; 
        } 

        if ("Customers".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){ 
            Customers(); return; 
        } 

        if ("Calculate Volume".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){ 
            Calculate_Volume(); 
            return;                                                                                            
        } 

        if ("Options".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){ 
            Options(); 
            return; 
        }
    } 

    private void Exit_pressed(){ 
        System.exit(0); 
    } 
    private void New_Name(){ 
        System.exit(0); 
    } 
    private void Calculate_Volume(){ 
        String lengthString, widthString, depthString; 
        int length=0; 
        int width=0; 
        int depth=0; 

        lengthString = lengthText.getText(); 
        widthString = widthText.getText(); 
        depthString = depthText.getText(); 
        if (lengthString.length() < 1 || widthString.length() < 1 || depthString.length() < 1){ 
            volumeText.setText("Error! Must enter in all three numbers!!");  
            return;                                                                                                    
        } 
        length = Integer.parseInt(lengthString ); 
        width = Integer.parseInt(widthString ); 
        depth = Integer.parseInt(depthString); 

        if (length != 0 || width != 0 || depth != 0){ 
            volumeText.setText((length * width * depth) + "" ); 
        }   
        else{ 
               volumeText.setText("Error! Must Enter in all three numbers!!"); 
               return; 
            } 
    } 

    private void Customers(){ 
    } 

    private void Options(){
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        JFrame frame = new VolCalc(); 
        frame.setSize(525, 350); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Errs:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: VolCac Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VolCac at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Exception in thread "main"

Comment: @Bartzilla, I'm sorry, what is the stacktrace?

Comment: So you had some errors (which you haven't given us details of) and you changed things (renaming some classes, but we don't know which), and now you've got new errors (which you haven't given us details of). Part of the problem may be in code you haven't posted. All in all, that makes it quite hard for us to answer the question. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - we're not psychic.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: VolCac
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VolCac
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"

Comment: @Mike: And how are you trying to run this? And has it actually *compiled* with no errors?

Comment: @Jon: Using Eclipse. No, I'm not able to run it. I would have posted all of the code for you, but it was too long and the forum wouldn't let me.

Comment: @Mike You need to provide more detail than this. First off, what are these "new error"s that you're referring to? Does the code generate compilation errors? Does it bomb out during execution? Or does it simply not do what you're expecting it to do when you run it?

Comment: @Kevin, I stated the errors four posts up.  These errors pop up at the bottom of my Eclipse window.

Comment: @Mike: I asked *how* you were trying to run it (there are various ways in Eclipse), and whether you'd managed to get it to *compile*. Different questions. What does the "Problems" tab in Eclipse show?

Comment: @Mike My fault, I didn't see your comment indicating the errors. The original question has been updated to show these errors now.

Comment: @Mike Can you produce a minimal example that reproduces your errors? Can you edit your above post to include that (in it's entirety) and describe, in detail, how we would reproduce your errors in Eclipse. If we have a lot of unnecessary code, and potentially don't have some important code, we can't work out what's wrong.

Comment: +1 to Edd's comment - with *minimal* being the key.

Comment: @Jon, I changed the code above to be able to run and show the errors I'm getting.  Thanks

Comment: @Mike: Well, I've just compiled and run that code (which is still far from minimal). It runs fine. So it must be to do with *how* you're running it, which you still haven't explained. What *exactly* are you doing to try to run it? (Key presses and mouse clicks.) See my answer for a guess as to what might be going on.

Comment: @Jon, I'm clicking the green run button at the top.

Comment: @Mike: Right, as I suggested in my answer. Chances are that's using the old class name. Now the first time you ran the code, you must have done something else - e.g. picked "Run as Java application" from a context menu. Do that again.

Comment: @Jon, That works running it like that.  How can I fix it so that it won't do that?

Comment: @Mike: When you rename a class, don't try to use a launch configuration using the old class name... either create a new one (e.g. by running it from the context menu) or edit the existing launch configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My *guess* is that you tried to use a previous launch configuration, which was using the old name. Launching the class from the context menu (or using the appropriate keyboard shortcut, which I can't remember now - something like Ctrl-Alt-X, J) will use the *new* name, and may solve the problem.

Alternatively, you could use the dropdown next to the "Run" button and edit the launch configuration to tell it the correct class name to launch.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know how you instantiate this but the stacktrace indicate the "VolCac" class is not found. In the code you pasted here, your class is named "VolCalc"...